# How can I improve the performance of this OpenCL Reduction Kernel code?

Tags: c++, performance, opencl

I've written code responsible for performing a Reduction on a large set of data, and while the code appears to be logically correct, it's proving to be slower than a simple `std::accumulate` or `std::max_element` call for the same data, and I'm looking for any insight into how I might have botched the performance of this code.

These are the results I'm getting. Note that even the raw time to execute the kernel is slower than a simple CPU reduction of my data.

```
Select which Device to use: 
0:                Cedar (AMD Accelerated P... - OpenCL 1.2 AMD-AP...)
1:                Cedar (AMD Accelerated P... - OpenCL 1.2 AMD-AP...)
2:         Intel(R) ... (AMD Accelerated P... - OpenCL 1.2 AMD-AP...)
3:         Intel(R) ... (Experimental Open... - OpenCL 2.0 (Build...)
Device: Cedar
Platform: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Num of compute units: 8
Work Group Size: 128
i = 9419918
Internal Duration:    95609555ns //Time to run just the kernel, no setup
Num of Work Groups to sum up: 78125
Reduced Value was detected to be:    -5.06886
(Index):                             1008460
Value at index is:                   -5.06886
Kernel Duration:     153748214ns //Includes copying of data, excludes building of kernel
Counting manually, Reduced Value is: -5.06886
(Index of):                          1008460
Value at index is:                   -5.06886
Manual Duration:      48173322ns //CPU runtime using std::max_element`.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The kernel code is constructed by concatenating all four of these files:

expand.cl

```
R"D(
#define EXPAND(type) \
typedef     type        Scalar;\
typedef     type ## 2   Vector2;\
typedef     type ## 4   Vector4;\
typedef     type ## 8   Vector8;\
typedef     type ## 16  Vector16;
)D"
```

float.cl

```
R"D(
EXPAND(float);

#define SCALAR_MAXIMUM INFINITY;
#define SCALAR_MINIMUM -INFINITY;
#define SCALAR_ZERO 0;
)D"
```

max.cl

```
R"D(
constant Scalar IDENTITY = SCALAR_MINIMUM;

#define REDUCE_IMPL(a, b, indexa, indexb, reduced_value, reduced_index) \
if(a > b) {\
    reduced_value = a;\
    reduced_index = indexa;\
} else {\
    reduced_value = b;\
    reduced_index = indexb;\
}
)D"
```

Reduction Main.cl

```
R"D(
kernel void reduce(global Scalar * a, global Scalar * output, local Scalar * scratch, global long * index_output, local long * index_scratch, long size) {
    size_t gid = get_global_id(0);
    size_t lid = get_local_id(0);
    size_t wid = get_group_id(0);
    size_t gsize = get_global_size(0);
    size_t lsize = get_local_size(0);
    size_t wsize = get_num_groups(0);

    if(gid < size) {
        scratch[lid] = a[gid];
        index_scratch[lid] = gid;
    } else {
        scratch[lid] = IDENTITY;
        index_scratch[lid] = -1;
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    for(size_t offset = lsize / 2; offset > 0; offset >>= 1) {
        if(lid < offset) {
            size_t indexa = index_scratch[lid];
            size_t indexb = index_scratch[lid + offset];
            Scalar a = scratch[lid];
            Scalar b = scratch[lid + offset];

            Scalar reduced_value;
            size_t reduced_index;

            REDUCE_IMPL(a, b, indexa, indexb, reduced_value, reduced_index);

            scratch[lid] = reduced_value;
            index_scratch[lid] = reduced_index;
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    if(lid == 0) {
        output[wid] = scratch[0];
        index_output[wid] = index_scratch[0];
    }
}
)D"
```

CL Reduction.h `perform_reduction`:

```
std::future<result> perform_reduction(std::vector<T> const& values) {
    cl_long size = values.size();
    uint64_t num_of_work_groups = size / work_group_size;
    int64_t global_size = work_group_size * num_of_work_groups;
    if (global_size < size) {
        num_of_work_groups++;
        global_size = work_group_size * num_of_work_groups;
    }
    cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, global_size * sizeof(T), nullptr);
    std::vector<cl::Event> write_events(1);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(input_buffer, false, 0, size * sizeof(T), values.data(), nullptr, &write_events.back());
    if (global_size != size) {
        write_events.emplace_back();
        queue.enqueueFillBuffer(input_buffer, reduction::identity<T>(), size * sizeof(T), (global_size - size) * sizeof(T), nullptr, &write_events.back());
    }
    return std::async([size, num_of_work_groups, global_size, input_buffer, write_events, this] {
        cl::Buffer output_buffer( context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, num_of_work_groups * sizeof(T) );
        cl::Buffer output_index_buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, num_of_work_groups * sizeof(cl_long));
        kernel.setArg(0, input_buffer);
        kernel.setArg(1, output_buffer);
        kernel.setArg(2, sizeof(T) * work_group_size, nullptr);
        kernel.setArg(3, output_index_buffer);
        kernel.setArg(4, sizeof(cl_long) * work_group_size, nullptr);
        kernel.setArg(5, size);

        std::vector<cl::Event> kernel_event;
        kernel_event.emplace_back();
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, {}, { uint64_t(global_size) }, { work_group_size }, &write_events, &kernel_event.back());
        std::vector<T> results;
        std::vector<int64_t> indexes;
        results.resize(num_of_work_groups);
        indexes.resize(num_of_work_groups);
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(output_buffer, false, 0, num_of_work_groups * sizeof(T), results.data(), &kernel_event);
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(output_index_buffer, false, 0, num_of_work_groups * sizeof(cl_long), indexes.data(), &kernel_event);
        queue.finish();
        std::cout << "Internal Duration: " << std::setw(11) << (kernel_event[0].getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() - kernel_event[0].getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>()) << "ns" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Num of Work Groups to sum up: " << num_of_work_groups << std::endl;
        result t{ reduction::identity<T>(), 0 };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            T const& val = results[i];
            size_t const& index = indexes[i];
            t = reduction::reduce(t.reduced_value, val, t.reduced_index, index);
        }
        return t;
    });
}
```

Reduction Main.cpp:

```
#define _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC 1
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include<fstream>
#include<chrono>
#include<numeric>
#include<random>
#include<iomanip>

#include "CL Reduction.h"

std::string limit(std::string string, size_t limit) {
    if (string.size() >= limit) return string.substr(0, limit - 3) + "...";
    else return std::move(string);
}

cl::Device choose_device() {
    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    for (cl::Platform const& platform : platforms) {
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        all_devices.insert(all_devices.end(), devices.begin(), devices.end());
    }

    std::cout << "Select which Device to use: " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < all_devices.size(); i++) {
        cl::Device const& device = all_devices[i];
        std::cout << i;
        std::cout << ": ";
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << limit(device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>(), 20);
        std::cout << " (";
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << limit(cl::Platform{ device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM>() }.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>(), 20);
        std::cout << " - ";
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << limit(device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>(), 20);
        std::cout << ")";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    size_t chosen;
    std::cin >> chosen;
    return all_devices[chosen];
}

int main() {
    using type = float;
    using reduction_type = cl_reduction_type::reduction_type<cl_reduction_type::type::maximum>;
    using datatype = cl_datatype::datatype<type>;
    using context_t = cl_reduction::reduction_context<datatype, reduction_type>;
    std::ofstream err_log{ "err.txt" };

    cl::Device device = choose_device();

    try {
        cl_reduction::reduction_context<datatype, reduction_type> context{ { device }, err_log };
        std::vector<type> values;
        auto last_ping = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::default_random_engine engine{ std::random_device{}() };
        std::uniform_real_distribution<type> distribution{ -100.f, 100.f };
        //std::uniform_int_distribution<type> distribution(1, 500);
        values.resize(10'000'000ull);
        //values.resize(10'000);
        type start = distribution(engine);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = start;
            start = std::nextafter(start, std::numeric_limits<type>::infinity());
            if (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - last_ping > std::chrono::seconds(1)) {
                std::cout << "i = " << i << '\r';
                last_ping += std::chrono::seconds(1);
            }
        }

        std::shuffle(values.begin(), values.end(), engine);

        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto future = context.perform_reduction(values);
        context_t::result t;
        try {
            t = future.get();
        }
        catch (cl::Error const& e) {
            err_log << e.what() << std::endl;
            err_log << e.err() << std::endl;

        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        std::cout << "Reduced Value was detected to be:    " << t.reduced_value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(Index):                             " << t.reduced_index << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value at index is:                   " << values[t.reduced_index] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Kernel Duration:   " << std::setw(11) << (end - begin).count() << "ns" << std::endl;
        begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        //auto value = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), type(0));
        auto it = std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
        auto index = std::distance(values.begin(), it);
        auto value = values[index];
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Counting manually, Reduced Value is: " << value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(Index of):                          " << index << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value at index is:                   " << values[index] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Manual Duration:   " << std::setw(11) << (end - begin).count() << "ns" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (cl::Error const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << ':' << e.err() << std::endl;
        if (e.err() == CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE)
            std::cerr << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE>() << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've included the entire codebase [here](https://github.com/Xirema/OCLReduction), which includes the three headers used and the main function.  ("CL Datatype.h", "Cl Reduction Type.h", "CL Reduction.h", "Reduction Main.cpp"). I've only included for this post the code that I think is relevant, but if you think the problem is in something else, you can point to that in the Github Repo.

Comment: Cedar has 100 GFLOPs peak performance with 80 processing elements which are VLIW architecture that needs vector processing, not scalar, to get gaster. Also peak performance is not always achievable. Try to make it vectorized and check if its hitting pci-e bandwidth limit or card's memory bandwidth limit(which isn't very different than pci-e bandwidth). Assumed its HD5450. Reading nearly 10 million scalars would be slower than reading 2-3 million vectors of width-4. Whats your CPU? I guess its a new part since it supports opencl 2.0 ? 10 million integer/float means 40 milliseconds(1GB/s)

Comment: the kernel part could be(maybe) optimizable to a vector version and the array copy part could be improved with map/unmap using a 4k-aligned array. So the data copy part may be reduced by %20-%30 and if vectorization works, it should reduce the kernel time by %40-%60. What speed the CPU gets with OpenCL? I guess its fastest(with map/unmap since its zero-copy access for CPU). I don't think it supports compute+copy asynchronously, if it supports then you can create a "pipeline" to push data and pop results from older data, but faster.

Comment: The input and output data type is `Scalar` which is 32 bit `float` and the local buffer is 64 bit `long`. Why? This may have impact on the performance. Also I wouldn't use `long` buffer for storing indexes unless you really really need to store such big values. Doubling the size of local memory certainly may affect the performance. You can explore this using CodeXL.

Comment: @doqtor Changing the index buffer + scratch space to use 32-bit ints instead of 64-bit ints speeds up the entire process (goes from 150ms to 110ms) but has no effect on the kernel runtime (stays at 90ms), and since the kernel runtime needs to get lower than the CPU runtime before I can start to consider these kinds of micro-optimizations, I'd rather focus on the algorithm being used, which I suspect is a much bigger player in terms of how performant my code is.

Comment: @doqtor Actually, checking the performance today, it looks like the speed is down to 110ms (90ms internal) regardless of what kind of indexes I use.  So there doesn't seem to be a meaningful difference right now.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik What would a vectorized version of `Reduction Main.cl` look like? It's not straightforward to simply change the datatypes and expect the same results.

Comment: @Xirema reducing `scratch[lid + offset] and scratch[lid+1 + offset] and scratch[lid +2 + offset] and scratch[lid +3 + offset]` at once should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Read your input with `Vector4 a = vload4(...)` and use `.xyzw`. You might also try vectorizing by 8 with `vload8`.

Instead of `a > b`, use `isgreater(a, b)` along with `any`, `all` and `select`.

Do more than one reduction per loop to keep it in registers and reduce the bandwidth to the local memory. For a workgroup size of 128 and vector size of 4, the first thread would reduce 0-3 with 512-515, then with 1024-1027, etc. before writing to local memory with `vstore4`. Try different inner loop sizes.

As much as possible, you don't want threads sitting around doing nothing. The kernel should just be reducing from global memory into registers once, storing to local memory and then synchronizing the threads before one thread reduces from local to a single value for the kernel and store that in global memory. Finally, you can do the last, relatively small, level of reduction on the CPU. This level will only contain one value from each workgroup: `total_size / (work_group_size = 128) / (vector_size = 4) / (inner_loop_size = 16)`